# how to generate the following layout in bootstrap 3 css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to generate the following layout in bootstrap 3 css but the side bar is always small and it does not properly scale up and there is issues in mobile mode how do I proceed. thanks in advance.

[image]

**Note:**
this is what I tried

```
    <div style="display:table;height:100%;width:100vw">
        <div style="display:table-row-group;height:100%;width:100vw">
               <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-half" style="background:black;height:100vh;"></div>
               <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11half">
<div id="prdgrid">
        <breadcrumbs path=prd.path ></breadcrumbs>

    <div class="row" style="width: 100%;height:100%">
        <div class="leftcol">
            <div class="infotile" style="height: 25%;">
                <infotile></infotile>
            </div>

        <div class="detail" style="height:31%">
            <details></details>
        </div>

        <div>
            <match></match>
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="rightcol" style="height:100%">
         <div class="pricetile hidden-xs">
             <pricechart></pricechart>
         </div>


            <div class="rightbottomcol" style="height:51%">
                <div class="rev">
                    <div class="title">
                        <tile></tile>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rev" style="height: 100%;">
                    <pd></pd>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>           
    </div>
```

Comment: show tour code please.

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried. If possible please post running fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Bootstrap Grid and Panel for Same Layout instead of  Creating own CSS layout. Refer Link : https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ and http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will the side bar increase with the increase of the content of the main area